# google map loaded in iframe not working in ie

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer

I am loading a google map in my website using this code

```
 <iframe width="96%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=+&amp;q=55.95143146710088,-3.1784801483154&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=55.961432,-3.19848&amp;spn=0.001811,0.004823&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

This working in all browsers except ie. I any thing wrong in this code. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please provide more information. Which version of IE is not displaying the page properly or what error message do you get? Have you checked the console ? I have tested upto IE8 and it is working fine.

Comment: in my console i got this error SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/myplaces/mp4.png

Comment: Have you tried removing https in the ifrmae src  and replace it with http ?